# Check if audio muted or not in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, audio, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find anything to help me verify if audio is muted or not.

There will be a flash video in web driver and I need to know if the the advertise before the video is on mute or not! Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: Flash uses a separate layer than the one controlled by Selenium. As a human, how do you know if the audio is muted? If it's an icon (or some other visible thing), take a screenshot, and check it. Or you could try to connect to the audio mixer of the operating system, checking if there is any sound going through (but there might be other apps making sound too, so it's quite unreliable I guess). Soundchecks (and generally Flash tests) are beyond the capabilities of Selenium.

Comment: i think it should be a way to know if there is audio from specific tab

Comment: Which player is the page using?

Comment: @Deeb Andrawis, there's probably a player on top of Flash with a specific api, can you provide the HTML?

Comment: @FlorentB.
<video style="width: 100%; height: 100%" autoplay="" class="vjs-tech" src="http://integration.hiro.tv/public/QA/Earth_from_International_Space_Station_sv.mp4" id="vjs_video_3_html5_api"></video>

Answer (score 0):

Selenium itself won't help but Java does. Take a look at the Java [AudioSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html) class.

```
Port lineIn;
FloatControl volCtrl;
try {
  Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(null);
  lineIn = (Port)mixer.getLine(Port.Info.LINE_IN);
  lineIn.open();
  volCtrl = (FloatControl) lineIn.getControl(

  FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);

  // Assuming getControl call succeeds, 
  // we now have our LINE_IN VOLUME control.
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Failed trying to find LINE_IN"
    + " VOLUME control: exception = " + e);
}
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html) for a discussion (search on mute).

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML indicates that the page is playing an HTML5 video and not Flash and that the player is VIDEOJS (http://videojs.com). 
Their documentation indicates that the API is HTML5 compliant, so this should work in your case:

```
boolean isMuted = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "return window.videojs('vjs_video_3_html5_api').muted()");
```

Note that you'll have to set the context to the parent frame if there's any before executing this code.

Comment: thanks , but i`m trying to check the ad before the video . so it is not working !
there is no way to check if there is a sound in such tab ? or in browser !?!?

Comment: With Selenium you can check if a component is muted as long as the component provides a Javascript API. This works fine for a VIDEOJS video. If it doesn't in your case, your add is probably in another component.